# Want to animate an object from left to right using CSS

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to animate a simple object in my site from left to right on the viewport but cannot figure out whats wrong with my code. Trying to do it in Microsoft VS Code.
code is produced below

```css
.ball {
    border: 5px solid red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation-name: moveBall;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation: alternate;
}

@keyframes moveBall {
    from {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    to {
        left: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```

would appreciate if someone can help me point out the problem in the code that is preventing the ball from moving from left to right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accidentally assigned `animation: alternate`. It is a shorthand that overrides the `animation-name`.

What you want is [`animation-direction: alternate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction)

FYI, `animation-direction: alternate` will not work if the `animation-iteration-count` is `1`(default), so you may also want to assign `animation-iteration-count: 2` or `animation-iteration-count: infinite` etc.

```css
.ball {
    border: 5px solid red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation-name: moveBall;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes moveBall {
    from {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    to {
        left: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```

Comment: oh gosh.... thank you so very much for pointing out where i went wrong.
it helped me sole my problem. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use --->             ''' Animations-direction'''
.   In place of--->  **Animation**